# Proof Cauchy's Theorem for abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Theorem**: $G$ an abelian group and $p$ a prime number with $p|\text{ord}(G)\Rightarrow \exists a\in G: \text{ord}(a)=p$.

The **proof** in my book begins with setting $n:=\text{ord}(G)$. For $n=1$ everything is clear and nothing to prove. Now it moves on to $n\geq2$ we can choose a $a\in G,a\neq e$ with $e$ denoting the neutral element of group $G$. It says that $p|\text{ord}(a) \Rightarrow \text{ord}(a)=n\cdot p \Rightarrow\text{ord}(a^n)=p$. I get the last bit but does not understand the part with $p|\text{ord}(a) \Rightarrow \text{ord}(a)=n\cdot p$. I know why this would be true for some $m$ but it denotes $n:=\text{ord}(G)$ in the beginning. Is this just a unlucky denotation or is it also true for $n:=\text{ord}(G)$ and if so, why?

Comment: You're right: the author should have used $m$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Fischer - Lerhbuch der Algebra (German Book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mistake, as the order of $a$ equal to $np$ implies $\operatorname {ord}(a)\gt |G|\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$.